# How to stop the UI navigating to the most recent result in the Services view?

Tags: datagrip

So I have maybe 10 different connections active at any one time, running a bunch of statements on different dbs. Every time a single statement/query is completed, my results view jumping to the latest completed statement in the console, on any one of the open running connections - which is annoying when its something like quickly dropping a temp table when i'm quickly reading results from another output.

Any idea if you can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is impossible now. Please file a feature request here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE

The workaround can be using 'In-editor results' mode, when you'll see the result just under your query and no one will ever grab it from you!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - i'll add a request to the backlog :)